# libcpr not working properly when using it for HTTP request

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http, authentication, httprequest

I am using libcpr for http requests in Visual Studio 2019 IDE. I downloaded it using vcpkg from microsoft. The sample code below is from cpr github page [https://github.com/libcpr/cpr#:~:text=%23include%20%3C,return%200%3B%0A%7D](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr#:%7E:text=%23include%20%3C,return%200%3B%0A%7D)

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cpr::Response r = 
             cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                  cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass", cpr::AuthMode::BASIC},
                  cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
    return 0;
```

}

This doesn't work! It is giving error "namespace "cpr" has no member "AuthMode". This problem is not with this only. There was some other stuff that gives similar error e.g. [https://docs.libcpr.org/advanced-usage.html#https-options:~:text=cpr%3A%3ASslOptions%20sslOpts%20%3D%20cpr%3A%3ASsl(ssl%3A%3ACaBuffer%7B%22%2D%2D%2D%2D%2DBEGIN%20CERTIFICATE%2D%2D%2D%2D%2D%5B...%5D%22%7D)%3B%0Acpr%3A%3AResponse%20r%20%3D%20cpr%3A%3AGet(cpr%3A%3AUrl%7B%22https%3A//www.httpbin.org/get%22%7D%2C%20sslOpts)%3B](https://docs.libcpr.org/advanced-usage.html#https-options:%7E:text=cpr%3A%3ASslOptions%20sslOpts%20%3D%20cpr%3A%3ASsl(ssl%3A%3ACaBuffer%7B%22%2D%2D%2D%2D%2DBEGIN%20CERTIFICATE%2D%2D%2D%2D%2D%5B...%5D%22%7D)%3B%0Acpr%3A%3AResponse%20r%20%3D%20cpr%3A%3AGet(cpr%3A%3AUrl%7B%22https%3A//www.httpbin.org/get%22%7D%2C%20sslOpts)%3B) in this case "CaBuffer" has same issue.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Recommendation: Copy the error message text and paste it into the question. There is a lot of information in a good error message and we can help you figure out how to read them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like a versioning issue. `AuthMode` exists in the [latest header file](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/blob/master/include/cpr/auth.h), but does not exist in the [version 1.8 header file](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/blob/1.8.x/include/cpr/auth.h), which is presumably what you have.

So, either downgrade your code, or upgrade your installation.

Sample code from version 1.8 is [here](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/tree/1.8.x)